# saving state of debugger in visual studio 2005

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there any way to save the state of debugger in vs2005 ?

I worked really long to reproduce some bug , and I want to save re reproduction , that latter I will be able to load it again.

Any idea if it is possible ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a dump from within Visual Studio and reload it later for further analysis, but it is only a static view.
However, you can't have a dynamic view unless you use Intellitrace only available on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (Intellitrace is only available for managed applications, not native ones).

Comment: @Thanks, This is exactly what I was afraid of .

Comment: Microsoft uses internally a tool to record program execution and replay it later (used by Microsoft support team). This is called iDNA but you can find it with other names as well. You can then replay the execution inside WinDbg. This technology is not available for us, poor third-party developers :-(

Answer (score -2):

Save the (im assuming .cpp) file in a different location then where it saves when you build your project. Open it back up when you want to see the code that caused the bug. I'm not sure of anyway to save the debugger directly but this should work for you.

This might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290350%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vstchdebugginginvisualstudionetanchor5

-Panda

Comment: It's .NET 1.1, so, yeah, by about a decade.

Comment: the link focuses on Visual Studio regardless. It was written in 2002 and still applies to Visual Studio 2005. Thanks for the -1 though.

Comment: You're welcome. People will follow your link and get lost in a [maze of twisty little](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure#Maze_of_twisty_little_passages) links, all about an obsolete version of the software.